# Append array at the beginning of the array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react js on this but I think this one is a Vanilla Javascript question.
What I want to achieve here is to push an array at the beginning of the lists of objects. current what I have is to append at the end of the object using concat:

```
this.setState({
            lists: this.state.lists.concat([result])
        });
```

How can I implement to push at the beginning of the array. This is what the data that will be push at the beginning:

[image]

Comment: In my opinion it's not a generic JS question, because when you're talking about React state, you usually don't want to mutate your data. That's why using a simple `this.state.lists.unshift(result)` is not the best thing you can do even though it works to some extent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you want is probably:

```
this.setState({
    lists: [result].concat(this.state.lists),
});
```

But if you're using ES6, there's also a nicer way:

```
this.setState({
    lists: [result, ...this.state.lists],
});
```